# Date range query in python script is rendering less result compare to same query in Postman/Kibana for elastic index

Tags: python, elasticsearch

Elastic query to get the results for every 5 mins
{

```
"query": {

    "bool": {

        "must": [{

                "match": {

                    "s": "fourier-core"

                }

            },

            {

                "bool": {

                    "should": [{

                            "wildcard": {

                                "apid": "Env*"

                            }

                        },

                        {

                            "wildcard": {

                                "apid": "Com*"

                            }

                        }

                    ]

                }

            },

            {

                "bool": {

                    "should": [{

                            "match_phrase_prefix": {

                                "auditMessage": {

                                    "query": "Replacing splice insert"

                                }

                            }

                        },

                        {

                            "match_phrase_prefix": {

                                "auditMessage": {

                                    "query": "Forwarding message to"

                                }

                            }

                        }

                    ]

                }

            }

        ],




        "filter": {

            "range": {

                "@timestamp": {

                    "gte": "now-5m"

                }

            }

        }

    }

}
```

}

We have tried same query in Python script and Postman.
Postman is rendering 683 records
Python script rendering 505 records only.
So I tried in node JS also, same issue is happening. Please let me know if any issue in query or something need to be added